# How to change the graphic settings in Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 15.04, plasma-5

and thanks for taking a look at my problem.
I have a Kubuntu 15.04, upgraded from 14.10 and whenever I open a session the borders in every breeze theme window show a black corner and the preview of the windows in the task bar look less defined than previously.
In 14.10 there was an option for this in the settings menu, but now on Plasma 5 I don't seem to find a similar one.
I did change the settings for the composition trying OpenGL 2.0, 3.1, GLX, EGL, and every combination possible without a solution.
If you know a way I would be very thankful.
Hope you have a good day, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Under System Settings open Display Configuration. On the Display Configuration tab scroll down (you may need to click the Unify outputs button) select your resolution and apply.